# Unable to write to AppEngine DataStore using web2py's DAL

Tags: python, database, google-app-engine, web2py

I've just started using web2py with Google AppEngine for an app of mine. For some reason, I'm unable to save/retrieve data using the DAL. Here's the code I'm using:

At the end of db.py:

```
from aeoid import middleware
from aeoid import users
import json


db.define_table('files', 
                    db.Field('name', 'text'),
                    db.Field('path', 'text'),
                    db.Field('version', 'text', default="live"),
                    db.Field('hash', 'text'),
                    db.Field('data', 'text'),
                    db.Field('meta', 'text', default=json.dumps({'date':str(request.now)})),
                    db.Field('contributors', 'text', default=json.dumps([users.get_current_user()])),
                    db.Field('lasttime', 'datetime', default=request.now)
                )
```

In my controller:

```
name = "TEST"
db.files[0] = dict(hash=name, name=name, path=name)
textobj = db.files[1]
if textobj is None:
  print "Fail: 500 Internal Server Error"
```

Here, textobj is always None for some reason.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: I'm using AppEngine SDK for Python on Windows.

Comment: Please don't use `print` inside a WSGI app.

Comment: I just put that as an example, here. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the [shortcut syntax](http://web2py.com/book/default/chapter/06#Shortcuts) `db.table[id]`, `id` refers to the record ID. `db.table[0]` doesn't actually refer to an existing record -- it is just used to insert a new record. 
Also, on GAE, the record IDs do not start at 1 and get incremented by 1, so your first inserted record will not have ID=1. You can either do:

```
textobj = db(db.files).select().first()
```

or

```
textobj_id = db.files.insert(hash=name, name=name, path=name)
textobj = db.files[textobj_id]
```

Finally, before deploying to GAE, make sure you have run the app locally using the GAE SDK appserver in order to properly generate the index.yaml file, as discussed [here](http://web2py.com/book/default/chapter/11#Configuration).

Comment: `db.files[1]` still gives me `None`

Comment: Have you run the app locally using the GAE SDK before deploying to GAE (see update above)?

Comment: I'm testing it locally, but I don't have an `index.yaml` file... How do I write it?

Comment: `index.yaml` is supposed to be generated automatically when you run the app locally with the GAE appserver. I'm not a GAE user, though, so can't easily help troubleshoot. I suggest you ask on the [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups&pli=1#!forum/web2py).

Comment: Updated the answer with further details.

Comment: This just works!!! Thank you very much, you are a life-saver.
So the problem was with the index after-all. 
Thank you.

Comment: `textobj = db(db.files.hash==name).select().first()` always gives `None`, what's the right way to do it? Thank you for your time, BTW.

Comment: That looks right to me. Does `db(db.files).select().first()` return any records (and if so, do any have the 'hash' field with the value of name)?

Comment: Yes, I can see it on the DataStore Viewer, but `db(db.files.hash==name).select()` gives an empty ROW object, so `db(db.files).select().first()` is `None`...

Comment: Can you confirm that the value of the `name` variable is what you think it is at the point you run this select? If the value of `name` is equivalent to the value of the `hash` field for at least one of the records, you should get a result.

Comment: Someone on the mailing list pointed out that you can't filter based on a text field on GAE. Instead, you can convert `hash` to a string field.